# Как извлекать объекты?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Задался таким вопросом. В `Ext JS` есть метод `Ext.getCmp('componentId')`. Он возвращает объект компонента, который является объектом класса (функции). При том, что не берет `HTML`-элемент по его ID, а реально объект. Ну так вот вопрос:
*По какому принципу этот метод работает? Или как можно извлекать созданные объекты по их ID?* Любые идеи и догадки.

PS:
Небольшое уточнение: метод извлекает по ID даже те элементы, которые находятся внутри других объектов (функций) разной вложенности и разного вида (даже те, которые были созданы таким образом: `var elem = new My.Element()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Истошно изучая исходники `Ext JS`, я все-таки нашел ответ на свой вопрос:

Там действует простое сохранение объектов в карту в глобальном объекте. В каждом объекте, в конструкторе, происходит добавление этого объекта в карту. И метод `getCmp()` извлекает и возвращает созданный ранее объект из карты. Естественно, в каждом объекте есть свойство `id`. Для большей наглядности, приведу код из исходника:

```
 //конструктор глобального объекта
//.....
 this.all = new Ext.util.HashMap();
 //.......
 /**
 * Returns a component by {@link Ext.Component#id id}.
 * For additional details see {@link Ext.util.MixedCollection#get}.
 * @param {String} id The component {@link Ext.Component#id id}
 * @return Ext.Component The Component, <code>undefined</code> if not found, or <code>null</code> if a
 * Class was found.
 */
get : function(id) {
    return this.all.get(id);
},

/**
 * Registers an item to be managed
 * @param {Mixed} item The item to register
 */
register: function(item) {
    this.all.add(item);
},
```

В принципе, удобный способ получить доступ к любому созданному в документе объекту.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElmentById("id"); // возвращает объект

document.elements["index/имя"]; // можно обращаться как к массиву
```

Comment: Прекрасно! Но это же `HTML`-элементы! Я про другое спрашивал. Как извлекать объекты классов (функций)?